# How to use BlobStore for uploading a file of DOC and PDF type

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, servlets, blobstore

I am tring a webapplication in GWT which uploads a file >1 MB and type doc and pdf.
I am using BlobStore.
Actually i have to store this file in the repository.Session of this repository is already created and is working fine.

Code

```
  // Get The URL
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
          System.out.println("blob" +blobServices);
        blobServices
            .getBlobStoreUploadUrl(callback) ;
      }
    });
```

The above RPC call is working fine i am able get the URL.
Now i have to use this URL with servlet which is used to upload a file.

```
   AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback() {

    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        caught.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onSuccess(Object result) {
    String tmp = result.toString();
        uploadForm.setAction(tmp);

        // Submit the form to complete the upload
        uploadForm.submit();
        uploadForm.reset();
    }
};
```

On server Side

```
 public class UploadServiceImpl extends HttpServlet {

       BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

    Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(req);
    BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("upload");
  }

 }
```

I dont know what to do after this. can any one tell me the code or the link to understand this part.
I want the size of the file and the content of the file.
the most Important is file is of type .doc and .pdf not image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't get the file name and type during the blobstore call, what I do is capture the file name on the client form and store it in a hidden field. When the user uses the uploadform you can grab the file name from whatever chooser you're using. Then when you post to your UploadServiceImpl you can get the file name from

req.getParameter(hiddenfieldname).